# Pass a variable from one IIFE to another

Tags: javascript, iife

I have an `index.html` file like this and several `.js` and `.css` files.
What I would like is to make the two `.js` files communicate with each other, I want to pass variables from one file to another.

**index.html**:

```
<html lang='en'>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8'>
        <script src='https://d3js.org/d3.v5.js' charset='utf-8'></script>
        <script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js'></script>  

        <link href='/css/a.css' rel='stylesheet'/>
        <link href='/css/b.css' rel='stylesheet'/>
        <link href='/css/c.css' rel='stylesheet'/>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id='a'></div>
        <div id='c'></div>
        <div id='b'></div>
    </body>

    <script src='/script/a.js' rel='script'/></script>
    <script src='/script/b.js' rel='script'/></script>
    <script src='/script/c.js' rel='script'/></script>
</html>
```

**a.js**

```
var MODULE = (function a() {

    var my = {};
    my.aToPass = 'a'; // variable to pass at file b.js

    var first = 5;
    var second = 'example';

    function test() {
        my.firstToPass = first + 100; // variable to pass at file b.js
        console.log(first);
    }

    return my;

}());
```

**b.js**

```
(function b() {

    console.log('my:', MODULE.my); // undefined
    console.log('my:', MODULE.aToPass); // undefined
    console.log('my:', MODULE.firstToPass); // undefined

    // other code...

}());
```

What I want is pass variables `aToPass` and `firstToPass` (of `a.js`) to `b.js` file. How can I do that?

I used the IIFE approach to split the code into several files but if there is a better way, I am willing to change the code structure.

Comment: You could consider using a standard module system such as Webpack, it's a great way to organize when you have larger amounts of code.

Comment: Not sure if it's recommended way but both of your `a.js` and `b.js` can pass in `global`/`window` object, and inject the variable `aToPass` and `firstToPass` into global object

Comment: @Isaac Can you post a simple example?

Comment: `console.log('my:', MODULE.my);` [works just fine](http://embed.plnkr.co/gtLG7LigGwMlUwHeMD5d/). A couple of notes: 1. `script` is not a valid child of `html`, move those *into* `body`, just prior to the closing `</body>` tag. 2. `rel` is not a valid attribute for [`script`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#the-script-element). But even without fixing those, it should (and does) work.

Comment: I think problem might be with your scipt tag with rel='script'

Comment: @sridhar.. - It's invalid, but probably ignored.

Comment: 3. You have an extra `/` before `>` in your opening `script` tag. It'll be ignored by the HTML parser, but it's still incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass an instance of the object to `b`.

In your `b` anonymous function...

```
(function b(MODULE) {

    console.log('my:', MODULE.my); // undefined
    console.log('my:', MODULE.aToPass); // undefined
    console.log('my:', MODULE.firstToPass); // undefined

    // other code...

})(MODULE);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
const MODULE = (function () {
      var my = {};

      my.aToPass = 'a'

      var first = 5;
      var second = 'example';

      (function test() {
        my.firstToPass = first + 100; // variable to pass at file b.js

      })();


      return my;
    })();


    module.exports = MODULE;
```

and b.js:

```
const MODULE = require('./try');

    (function b() {

      console.log('my:', MODULE.my); // undefined
      console.log('my:', MODULE.aToPass); // my: a
      console.log('my:', MODULE.firstToPass); // my: 105

      // other code...
    })();
```