# How to access variables inside one IIFE from another using templates?

Tags: javascript, html, templates, iife

There is some logic in the `base.html` file. I want to make its correspondent `js` file simpler and to put some functions aside.

Is there a way to access variables inside one [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE) (`main.js`) from another (`additional.js`)?

**base.html**

```
<body>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
    {% block extra_scripts %}
    {% endblock %}
</body>
```

**main.js**

```
(function(){
    var test = 123;
})();
```

**extension.html**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block extra_scripts %}
    <script src="additional.js"></script>   
{% endblock %}
```

**additional.js**

```
(function(){
    alert(test);
})();
```

This [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50524087/7127824) gives me undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to declare the variable outside and make it global to be accessible by other functions.

```
var test;
(function(){
    test = 123;
})();
```

Now, when

```
(function(){
    alert(test);
})();
```

runs `test` is within the scope and hence accessible. However, the order needs to be maintained, else test will be `undefined` for it is not yet defined.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it if you turn it into js module.

```
var mainModule = (function(){
    var test = 123;

    return {
       getTest: function() { return test;}
    }
})();
```

then in additional.js

```
mainModule.getTest();
```

Answer (score 1):

The variable defined inside a function has a scope in that function only and cannot be accessed outside .

You can globally declare the variable `test`

Answer (score 1):

variable which is scoped in function level can not be accessed outside. Either define the variable outside or add it to the window object in order to get accessed.

### main.js

```
(function(){
    window.test = 123;
})();
```

### additional.js

```
(function(){
    alert(test);
})();
```